# Page downloads as file in Chrome

Tags: php, plugin-wp-supercache, apc

I'm looking to see if I could get pointers in where to look to solve this issue.

### Issue

In Chrome, viewing the blog http://www.bitesizeirishgaelic.com/blog/ in Chrome v21, the page downloads as a file "download", rather than opening normally.

The rest of the site on the same server loads fine in Chrome.

All pages load fine in Firefox.

### Background

I suspected that it was something to do with the APC caching for Apache, and/or WP Super Cache. However, after disabling both, and clearing my browser cache, the problem continues.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me... Could you [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) the file that gets downloaded for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [page is sent](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://www.bitesizeirishgaelic.com/blog/&http=1.1&gzip=yes) with:

```
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

Change the Content-Type to `text/html`.

Comment: The content type returned is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` according to `curl -I`.

Comment: Enable gzip support in curl.

Comment: For future reference, that's `curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' <url>`.

Comment: This answer didn't "solve" the issue, but did point out the problem. Here's a summary of what fixed the problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/439470/setting-correct-content-type-sent-from-wordpress-on-apache-server